# Python: how to generate a list of "flattened" lists out of a big nested list

Tags: python, list

Let us say I have a list like the following:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]], [7, 8], 9]
```

I want to know how to flatten this list in the following manner:

```
[
    [7, 8],
    [5, 6],
    [3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]
```

Putting it into words, I want to know how to generate a list out of each of the levels of the main list, each list generated being a flattened version of all its sublists.

**EDIT:**

If the method is a left-recursion one, it is likely that the outputted list will have the lists in the following order (and not the order above):

```
[
    [5, 6],
    [3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]
```

Comment: Why not `[5, 6]` first? Followed by `[3, 4, 5, 6]`, then `[7, 8]` then `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`..

Comment: That could actually be the case, but in the end the order of the lists in the main outputted list does not matter for me in the final solution.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I can easily write the code for flattening a list, for example, but I couldn't come up with a code for that problem yet.

Comment: So... where is it? What have you tried, and exactly how did it come up short? Do you have any ideas, even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive generator function:

```
def yield_and_flatten(nested):
    """Yield sublists and flatten, recursively

    Produces a boolean and list on each yield; the boolean
    flags a merge; sublists are merged just once then
    passed down the recursion tree.

    """
    if not isinstance(nested, list):
        yield True, nested
        return
    res = []
    for elem in nested:
        for extend, sub in yield_and_flatten(elem):
            if isinstance(sub, list):
                if extend:
                    res.extend(sub)
                yield False, sub
            else:
                res.append(sub)
    yield True, res
```

This passes on sublists before extending the current level.

Demo:

```
>>> sample = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]], [7, 8], 9]
>>> for _, res in yield_and_flatten(sample):
...     print res
... 
[5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> mlist = [1, 2, 3, [[4, [5, 6]], 7], 8, 9]
>>> for _, res in yield_and_flatten(mlist):
...     print res
... 
[5, 6]
[4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Hi Martjin Peters, thanks for the answer. I've just noticed what you did there. In the solution I am looking for, though, there would be no repetition of inner elements (like in the last list your program outputs: `[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Namely, instead of that list, the last list should be just `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, or if you prefer `[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks @martijn-pieters.  I'll study the code.